# Windows forms build date format

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, desktop-application

I have a windows forms application. When I build the application, 'date modified' format of exe in the debug folder becomes '**d/MM/yyyy HH:mm**'. The other files in debug folder has '**dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm**' format. Can I set the date format for exe?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Are you talking about looking at the set of build files in Windows Explorer?  Different file-types don't have different date formats.

Comment: The format of the date and time in the file properties depends on the settings of the operating system.

Comment: But the dll files are in different format than exe.

Comment: Can you give examples?  The format may just drop leading 0s, so September 9 would be 9/9 but October 10 would be 10/10

Comment: To clarify, the build process just puts a timestamp on the file.  Explorer decides how to display that timestamp based on configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set the format of file dates as some attribute of the build process.  The build process attaches the current system timestamp to the file when it is created.

What you are seeing is how Windows chooses to show the timestamp based on the current configuration.  There is no formatting per file extension, so in that sense there is no difference between an .exe and any other file.  The default format you currently have setup allows for the dropping of leading zeros, so April is 4, not 04.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the modified date using [File.SetLastWriteTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It occurs after build or rebuild. I guess I don't have to do something in runtime for build-date format. Thank you for your help.